# rails image within a div tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="post feature-post" style="background-image:url(images/post/w1.jpg); background-size:cover;"> </div>
```

I then have an uploaded picture which can be accessed like so:

```
<%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %>
```

I need the uploaded image to be replace the background-image in the div here:

```
background-image:url(images/post/w1.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<div class="post feature-post" style="background-image:url(<%= post.image.url(:medium) %>); background-size:cover;"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Raphael's answer. Use this code, it worked for me

```
<div class="post feature-post" style="background-image:url(<%= post.image %>); background-size:cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;"> </div>
```